# How can we translate Promise for computer science into Chinese?

Tags: translation

https://axios-http.com/ In this website, it introduce `axios` as `a simple promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js.` So, how can we translate `promise` here?

> Axios is a simple promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js. Axios provides a simple to use library in a small package with a very extensible interface. -https://axios-http.com/

> Axios 是一个基于 promise 的网络请求库，可以用于浏览器和 node.js。—— https://axios-http.com/docs/intro

In my opinion, `promise` means a tool to retrive HTTP requests and responde to clients.

个人认为，`promise` 表示一个能获取 HTTP 并做出相应的工具。

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't translate, in such scenario.

similar words like:

```
docker
k8s
java
socket
websocket
ping 
stack
overflow
overwrite
pattern
cpu
response
request
web3
...
```

don't translate them, just keep them as English, thank you !

Comment: socket 套接字；stack 栈；overflow 溢出；overwrite 重写；pattern 模式；response 响应；request 请求。大部分也是有中文翻译的。我的意思是为什么不试着翻译呢？或者有没有人曾经翻译过呢？

Comment: I agree with @prettypig that lots of these words have conventional Chinese translations, even though practitioners sometimes just use English. For "promise" specifically though, I can't find any real tutorials that refer to it in Chinese rather than the English "Promise".

Comment: @prettypig 因为在职场上没人这么说.  随便找个论坛试试你就知道了.  还有:docker,  k8s,  github,  git repo.  commit.

Comment: 一些编程相关的名词是有官方的汉语翻译的，像“类（class）”、“封装（encapsulation）”、“返回值（return value）”等等，只是不知道国人有没有一致的对Promise的翻译。我个人的话会称之为“承诺”。“This is a promise-based API” =>　”这是一个基于承诺的API”

Answer (score 0):

I have found some blogs/tutorials that refer to it using 承诺, but most of the ones I found just say "promise" rather than translating it.

Answer (score 0):

The improvised translation would seem to be "promise object": 承諾物件, though in cases where one is referring to literal code (e.g., in HTML as `<code>Promise</code> object`) it should be left untranslated.

Answer (score 0):

Other than "承诺", "約定", promise also means "预示" - "预先显示" (事物在酝酿产生的过程中、在形成之前，在初始孕育阶段所显现的短暂而轻微的征象.)

You can check to see if this interpretation fits the context or not.